# Need more efficient solution of my `simple JS` code

Tags: javascript

Input string:

```
name|value|other,name2|value2|other2,name3|value3|other3
```

output:

```
value,value2,value3
```

Below is my code :

```
var op = str.split(",").map((x)=>x.split("|")[1]).toString();
console.log(op);
```

I don`t want a nested split, I need a more efficient solution to this.

Comment: Not sure whether it is *more efficient* but, if you do not want to use the second `split()`, an altrnative could be using `String.prototype.slice()` in combination of `String.prototype.indexOf()` and `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()` in order to get whatever is between the first and the last "|"

Comment: ... by the way, I'd replace the last `.toString()` with `.join(',')` in order not to rely on implicit joining.

Comment: @pannusharma what you posted is what you do *not* want, not an attempt to achieve what you want.

Comment: @secan I am not sure what effort you expect from the OP when they have no clue for to accomplish it. lol

Comment: "Not sure whether it is more efficient but..."; apparently it actually is more efficient: https://jsben.ch/X6qla

Comment: _..see carefully...._ No you have **not** posted your attempt to **find a more efficient solution**. Read comments carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
var op = str.split("|"); 
var result = ""; 
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i+=2)
    result += (op[i] + ","); 
result += op[5]; 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a wiz on regex, so I can't say if this is really more efficient because I use lookahead and lookbehind.

`(?<=\|)` : Look ahead, if there is a |
`([^,]+)`  : hit on any character combination, except if there is a ,
`(?=\|)`: Look behind, if there is a |

```js
let string = "name|value|other,name2|value2|other2,name3|value3|other3";
let extractSecondValue = /(?<=\|)([^,]+)(?=\|)/g;
let matchesArr = string.match(extractSecondValue);

console.log(matchesArr.toString());
```